# How to use tesseract.js improve accuracy

Tags: javascript, tesseract

I want to recognize English text from [the cat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waA3j.jpg). This is my source code. The output text is as follows. How to improve the recognition rate, making the string **Vou** will be converted to the string **You**, the string **advrce** will be converted to string **advice**.
[image]
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/0.2.0/dist/tesseract.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" />
<input type="button" id="go_button" value="Run" />
<div id="ocr_results"> </div>
<div id="ocr_status"> </div>
<script>
function runOCR(url) {
    Tesseract.recognize(url,{lang:'eng'})
         .then(function(result) {
            document.getElementById("ocr_results")
                    .innerText = result.text;
         }).progress(function(result) {
            document.getElementById("ocr_status")
                    .innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
                        (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
        });
}
document.getElementById("go_button")
        .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
            runOCR(url);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?